# Subadditivity of Linear Functional defined via Inf

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $B$ be a the set of all real valued functions bounded by $M$. Let $Y$ be a linear subspace of non-negative functions. Define $l$ to be a positive linear functional on $Y$ and let $$p(x) = \inf_{x \leq y} l(y) \quad \forall x\in B, y \in Y$$ We'd like to show $p$ is subadditive.

The proof I'm looking at looks proceeds as follows:

> Consider $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $B$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $Y$ such that $x_1 \leq y_1$ and $x_2 \leq y_2$. Adding the two we obtain $x_1 + x_2 \leq y_1 + y_2$ so:
>   $$p(x_1 + x_2) = \inf_{x_1 + x_2 \leq y}l(y) \\ \leq\inf_{x_1 \leq y_1 \\x_2 \leq y_2} l(y) \quad (*)\\ = \inf_{x_1 \leq y_1} l(y_1) + \inf_{x_2 \leq y_2} l(y_2) \quad (*) \\ p(x_1) + p(x_2)$$

I didn't understand how properties of infs were used in the two starred steps. In particular:

1. Why inequality between first and second line? Its not obvious to me that the set $\{x_1+x_2 \leq y\} \subset \{x_1 \leq y_1 \cup x_2 \leq y_2\}$
2. What's going on with the equality from the second to third line?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "linear subspace of non-negative functions"? I don't see how that is a linear space. What is the ordering for functions?

Comment: Suppose $S$ is the domain of functions in $B$. there's a partial ordering on functions. $x < y$ implies $x(s) < y(s) \,\, \forall s \in S$

Comment: what do you mean by $\inf (y)$ and how does $y$ relate to $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: oh no! those are typos, they are fixed. I meant $l(y)$, $l(y_1)$, and $l(y_2)$